# how could i decompress a lib.a file in xcode project?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I want to remove a class in a lib file in Xcode project. Is there a command to decompress lib.a? And how to compress it after i remove the class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lib is a fat file, you should thin it at first,then get the single thin lib file.
Run this command, it will list classes in your lib.a.Find out the class you want to remove.

```
ar -t lib.a
```

Compress *.o files to a newlib.a

```
ar rcs newlib.a /path(your *.o folder)
```

Hope it works!